# How to write rsync command to backup everything except hardware specific files

Tags: rsync, incremental-backup

I have a VPS production server that serves web apps that I make for clients. I have an rsync cron job running on my dev server that does a daily backup of the entire production server.

```
#!/bin/sh

RSYNC=/usr/bin/rsync
SSH=/usr/bin/ssh
KEY=/root/backup-rsync-key
RUSER=root
RHOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
LPATH=/home/backup
RPATH=/

$RSYNC -avz -e "$SSH -i $KEY" $RUSER@$RHOST:$RPATH $LPATH
```

It works OK but gives errors of the type:

```
...
rsync: read errors mapping "/sys/module/yenta_socket/parameters/disable_clkrun": No data available (61)
ERROR: sys/module/yenta_socket/parameters/isa_probe failed verification -- update discarded.
rsync: read errors mapping "/sys/module/yenta_socket/parameters/isa_probe": No data available (61)
ERROR: sys/module/yenta_socket/parameters/pwr_irqs_off failed verification -- update discarded.
rsync: read errors mapping "/sys/module/yenta_socket/parameters/pwr_irqs_off": No data available (61)
ERROR: sys/power/state failed verification -- update discarded.
rsync: read errors mapping "/sys/power/state": No data available (61)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at main.c(1298) [generator=2.6.8]
```

(this is just a snippet of the errors)

How can I backup everything except for the stuff that won't backup?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to exclude unnecessary files.

Good start is -x

```
-x, --one-file-system       don't cross filesystem boundaries
```

(from man rsync(1)). That excludes filesystems you didn't specify explicitly. Remember that then you have to list all mount points you want to include. `mount` gives list for you.

Another useful option is `--exclude`:

```
--exclude=PATTERN       exclude files matching PATTERN
--exclude-from=FILE     read exclude patterns from FILE
```

Your command would be something like

```
rsync -avzx --exclude=/tmp --exclude=/var/cache -e "$SSH -i $KEY" $RUSER@$RHOST:$RPATH $LPATH
```

Comment: Thanks - I've just been testing your solution and it appears to work now without any errors appearing. I also excluded /sys and /proc since they were causing a few errors.

Comment: You should exclude `/tmp` too, backing up temporary files is foolish.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude specific files using the --exclude option, like '--exclude=/sys'. Also, you can use the --exclude-from option to exclude files listed in a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `--exclude-from` command line option that allows you to define a file that contains a list of files and directories that rsync should exclude.